# Inverse transform image in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, image-scaling

I am using this code to translate an image but when I apply inverse on the image it did not show the whole image it shows only transformed image.

```
tran= [1 0 0; 0 1 0; -130 -100 1];
traninv= [1 0 0; 0 1 0; 130 100 1];
% apply translation
tform= maketform('affine', tran);
 ttform=maketform('affine', traninv);
 out=imtransform(img, tform, 'XData',[1 size(img,2)],'YData',[1 size(img,1)]);
 figure;
 imagesc(out);
 title ('translated image');
 colormap gray
 ot=imtransform(out, ttform, 'XData',[0 size(out,0)],'YData',[0 size(out,0)]);
 figure;
 imagesc(ot);
  title ('inverse translated image');
  colormap gray
```

Comment: use `tformarray` instead of `imtform` it handles translations in a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem comes from the size of the XData and YData you provide imtransform. Since they correspond to the size of the original image and the later is translated, MATLAB padds with 0 to fill the blanks but since you specify that you want a particular dimension for your image you seem to get only part of the image.

Here is a workaround to show you that your translation does work:

1) Create a canvas containing the original image; the canvas is large enough to contain the image and the rest is just black. I use the coins image that ships with MATLAB.

```
img = imread('coins.png');

%// Get size of original image

[height,width,~] = size(img)

canvas = zeros(2*size(img),'like',img);

%// Put image in canvas.
canvas(height+1:end,width+1:end) = img;

figure;
imagesc(canvas)
colormap gray
title('Original image','FontSize',16)
```

Looking like this:

[image]

Then apply your code to translate the image. Notice that change in XData and YData in imtransform:

```
tran= [1 0 0; 0 1 0; -130 -100 1];
traninv= [1 0 0; 0 1 0; 130 100 1];

% apply translation
tform= maketform('affine', tran);
ttform=maketform('affine', traninv);
out=imtransform(canvas, tform, 'XData',[1 size(canvas,2)],'YData',[1 size(canvas,1)]); %// Size is important!

figure;
imagesc(out);
title ('translated image','FontSize',16);
colormap gray

ot=imtransform(out, ttform, 'XData',[1 size(canvas,2)],'YData',[1 size(canvas,1)]);
figure;
imagesc(ot);
title ('inverse translated image','FontSize',16);
colormap gray
```

which gives the following translated image:

[image]

and inverse-translated image:

[image]

which looks exactly like the original. Note that it is preferable to use `affine2d` combined with `imwarp` instead of `maketform` and `imtransform`, but that's your call.

Hope that helps!

Comment: when i translate the image some of its part goes out.

Comment: As you are translating image within the dimension but my image goes out of the dimension and the image within the dimension only shown in figure

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean; you can try with a much larger canvas maybe? What is the size of the image you are trying to translate?

Comment: the image is stored in .pgm file.

Comment: here is the link to the photo of images
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0sEKy3ufKqeTlptZmpHWWtyQ1E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: ok so then you can open it with imread('ImageName.pgm'); and get its size. Actually simply do size(img). What do you get?

Comment: I edited the code to make it more general please try it.

Comment: +1 - Good job Benoit!  This definitely works.  If the OP can't get it to work... well... too bad!

Comment: its still giving same answer

Comment: well that should work. Instead of a screenshot from your desktop can you upload the actual picture you are using? Or maybe try rgb2gray(img) in case its a RGB image, which I doubt.

Comment: Thank yo soo much i got my answer.. :)

Comment: that's great then! What was the problem?

Comment: Am not implementing these line of codes

     canvas = zeros(2*size(img),'like',img);.
     canvas(height+1:end,width+1:end) = img;

when i add them in the start it gives larger space than the picture soo where i move the image it comes back to original transform again